# Change the logo displayed in magento 2 checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout-page, logo

I want to change the logo that is being displayed in the checkout page. For rest of the pages the logo should remain same. Also, I should be able to manage this via admin panel.

Please check the attached screenshots:-

- Logo in the home page:- **https://prnt.sc/r89rxt**
- I want to change the logo in checkout page:- **https://prnt.sc/r89skp**

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use helper

Override default.xml in your theme and add helper in **logo_file** argument

> Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="helper" helper="Vendor\Module\Helper\Data::getLogo"></argument>
```

In your helper, you can get logo based on current url like this.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $_request;

    public function __construct
    (
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    ) {
        $this->_request = $request;
    }

    public function getLogo()
    {
        if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'checkout_index_index') {
            $logo =  'images/{{custom.png}}';
        } else {
            $logo = 'images/{{default.png}}';
        }

        return $logo;
    }
}
```